# How to add meta value in page url?

Tags: wordpress

I want to call meta value in page url.
Example:
$var = "India";

now i want to use it with page url like http://localhost/demo/area/?meta_value

I don't know how to call like this. please help somebody. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

its done by myself. I am posting solution for everyone.
i used http://localhost/demo/area/?meta_value?=$var in my template and in link page template i used query post with 
$meta = $_REQUEST['meta_value'];
meta_value => $var

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
 $path = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
  $var = $_REQUEST['meta_value'];
?>

 <a href="<?php echo $path; ?>?meta_value=<?php echo $var; ?>">Click</a>
```